# Jmp from one function to another?

Tags: assembly, x86

If I call a function, can I use a `jmp` command within that function to go back to part of a different function? That is to say, is this code valid:

```
testfunction PROC
    jmp jumppoint
    ret
testfunction ENDP


main PROC
jumppoint:
    call testfunction
main ENDP
END
```

If this is valid, it should produce an infinite loop. Yes/no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'valid' you mean will the assembler let you do it, the answer is yes.  It will introduce a sort of infinite loop; however, since the `call` instruction will place additional information on the stack (a return address) each time it's executed, eventually the stack will overflow and the program will crash (maybe not if you're running in real mode).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is valid and It will produce an infinite loop, why don't you run it and see if you are right?

Of course the stack will over-follow since it is finite `0xFFFFFFFF` `>= esp` `> 0`